# Can CMS allow users to publish changes to a pre set date and time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-settings

I am developing a CMS website by using DotNetNuke. Requirement is like that, The Admin can change the content of any page and he/she also want to set date time at which the changes will be published to the website. Is this achievable? If yes the How?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

You can set start and end dates for each module in DNN (via module settings).  However, if you want to change the content within the module without replacing the module itself, that will depend on whether the module supports start/end dates.

Comment: Can we set it for the Draft that we saved after change page content?

Comment: No, I don't believe that there is any timing built into the workflow in DNN.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do that with this module: [dnnGo xBlog](http://www.dnngo.net/OurModules/xNews.aspx)

You can create an article and set it's **Start Date** and **Expiration Date**.

The article will show up on the StartDate and disappear on the EndDate.

Comment: Can we do the same for Pages also?

Comment: Not that I have seen.  You could make a module that could do that, but I've never seen any settings or modules that enable/disable pages on a  preset date.  You would need to write a DNN Scheduled Task to enable/disable the page in it's settings.  Ex: http://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2011/01/18/creating-dotnetnuke-scheduled-jobs.aspx